# Count with table() and exclude 0's

Tags: r, count

I try to count triplets; for this I use three vectors that are packed in a dataframe:

```
X=c(4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)              
Y=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,2,2,2,2,3,4,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4)
Z=c(4,4,5,4,4,4,4,4,6,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,7,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)


Count_Frame=data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow=(length(X)), ncol=3))

Count_Frame[1]=X
Count_Frame[2]=Y
Count_Frame[3]=Z

Counts=data.frame(table(Count_Frame))
```

There is the following problem: if I increase the value range in the vectors or use even more vectors the "Counts" dataframe quickly approaches its size limit due to the many 0-counts. Is there a way to exclude the 0-counts while generating "Counts"?

Comment: Do you want frequency of unique row combinations?

Answer (score 3):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(Count_Frame)`), grouped by all the columns (`.(X, Y, Z)`), we get the number or rows (`.N`).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Count_Frame)[,.N ,.(X, Y, Z)]
#    X Y Z N
# 1: 4 1 4 7
# 2: 4 1 5 1
# 3: 1 1 6 1
# 4: 1 1 1 3
# 5: 1 2 1 2
# 6: 1 3 1 1
# 7: 1 4 1 1
# 8: 2 2 2 4
# 9: 2 3 7 1
#10: 2 4 2 1
#11: 3 1 3 2
#12: 3 2 3 2
#13: 3 3 3 2
#14: 3 4 3 2
```

Instead of naming all the columns, we can use `names(Count_Frame)` as well (if there are many columns)

```
setDT(Count_Frame)[,.N , names(Count_Frame)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this with `aggregate`:

```
Count_Frame$one <- 1
aggregate(one ~ X1 + X2 + X3, data=Count_Frame, FUN=sum)
```

This will calculate the positive instances of `table`, but will not list the zero counts.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to create a combination of the column values and count those instead:

```
library(tidyr)
as.data.frame(table(unite(Count_Frame, tmp, X1, X2, X3))) %>%
  separate(Var1, c('X1', 'X2', 'X3'))
```

Resulting output is:

```
   X1 X2 X3 Freq
1   1  1  1    3
2   1  1  6    1
3   1  2  1    2
4   1  3  1    1
5   1  4  1    1
6   2  2  2    4
7   2  3  7    1
8   2  4  2    1
9   3  1  3    2
10  3  2  3    2
11  3  3  3    2
12  3  4  3    2
13  4  1  4    7
14  4  1  5    1
```

Answer (score 2):

Or using `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
count(Count_Frame, colnames(Count_Frame))
```

output

```
# > count(Count_Frame, colnames(Count_Frame))
   # X1 X2 X3 freq
# 1   1  1  1    3
# 2   1  1  6    1
# 3   1  2  1    2
# 4   1  3  1    1
# 5   1  4  1    1
# 6   2  2  2    4
# 7   2  3  7    1
# 8   2  4  2    1
# 9   3  1  3    2
# 10  3  2  3    2
# 11  3  3  3    2
# 12  3  4  3    2
# 13  4  1  4    7
# 14  4  1  5    1
```